# PHP, MySQL and Join with SUMs

Tags: php, mysql, join, sum

Long time listener, first time caller. Hope I don't screw up my first question! I am working on a report generation application, and I've just run into my first situation where I need a fairly complicated query.

Table 1 is called 'performance' and contains the columns 'merchant_id', 'publisher', 'sales', 'orders', and 'report_date'.

Table 2 is called 'publishers' and contains the columns 'publisher_id', 'publisher', 'status', 'location', and a few others.

I need to put in my report the top ten performers ordered by sales. I need their name (publisher), their ID (publisher_id), their sales total (sales), orders total (orders) and all those things within a specified time period (report_date) and for a specific merchant (merchant_id).

I am completely new to JOINs. This is what I have tried so far:

```
$sql = "SELECT
        performance.publisher,
        publishers.publisher_id,
        SUM(performance.orders) AS orders,
        SUM(performance.sales) AS sales
        FROM performance
        INNER JOIN publishers
        ON performance.publisher=publishers.publisher
        WHERE performance.merchant_id='$merchant->ID'
        AND (performance.report_date BETWEEN '{$dateStart}' AND '{$dateEnd}')
        GROUP BY publishers.publisher_id
        ORDER BY sales DESC LIMIT 10";
```

I then run the query and create an array of the results.

And what is returned is indeed ten results! The publisher and publisher_id are returned correctly. It's the sums that are messed up. I've tried messing with the start and end dates, to no avail. I just can't see where the returned numbers are coming from.

How should I structure the query?

Hopefully this question isn't too specific or narrow - if so I'm happy to try to rewrite it to be more valuable to a broader audience.

EDIT:

A vital piece of information was left out of my original summation. The publishers table also has a column called 'merchant_id' and each publisher will be entered into this table on a per-merchant_id basis. For example, publisher John Doe, publisher_id 123, merchant_id 12345 AND publisher John Doe, publisher_id 123, merchant_id 56789.

When I did the join, I expected to get results only related to a specific merchant_id, as you can see by the WHERE clause. But that WHERE clause only took the merchant_id of the performance table into account. It needs to take the merchant_id in the publisher's table into account as well. Now I just need to figure out the query structure for that.

I'm new to StackOverflow, so thank you all for being patient and offering questions and advice. I don't know if editing like this is the proper thing to do or if I'm supposed to create an Answer to the question or what.

Comment: Could you make an sql fiddle with some test-data?

Comment: Almost forgot: the $merchant->ID and $dateStart and $dateEnd variables are set before execution of the query (of course) and are being set correctly. They are not contributing to the problem. That was the first thing I checked.

Comment: Looks okay, as @Naruto said an SQl Fiddle with data would help. One thing I notice is you are SUMming order, if order is an ID you probably want to use COUNT() instead (IE count of orders rather than sum of orders value).

Comment: @DanielM.Clark do I get it correct? `performance.publisher` holds Title of publisher? not the `publisher_id`?

Comment: I've just looked up what sql fiddle is and I'm working with it now, thanks for that. Orders is a quantity of orders that a customer has placed. And performance.publisher does hold the name of the publisher, same as publishers.publisher. The publisher_id is a numerical value.

Comment: You connect the two tables using the field 'publisher'. What type of field is that? Normally would you connect two tables using a foreign key refering to a primary key. Now can you get data from publishers with the same name but a different id or can you not get data from the correct publisher, because the name has changed over time.

Comment: could you post here sample of raw data? and result you have? and expected result??

Answer (score 0):

Three things:

1. Make sure you know the difference between `SUM()` and `COUNT()`. It seems like you may be using `SUM()` on your orders where `COUNT()` is what you need.
2. You are misusing the pernicious MySQL extension to `GROUP BY`. Read this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html Try `GROUP BY performance.publisher, publishers.publisher_id` in place of what you have.
3. Be aware that JOIN operations, by their nature, cause a combinatorial explosion of rows in the result set. Every pair of rows that match your `ON` condition will show up in the result. This can cause double- or multiple- counting in your results. It's not clear whether you are double-counting. But be aware of it.

Comment: 1. Yep, I'm okay with the SUMs. They're used properly. Every row of the performance table is a day's amount of orders (a number) and sales (a dollar amount). The goal is to sum up all the orders and sales between two dates.

2. I tried that with no change in the result, but I will read more about GROUP BY, thanks.

3. Now we're onto something. The sales and orders are both off by 8 times their expected value. Clearly they are being sum'ed multiple times - 8 times exactly! That's where I am focusing the investigation now, thanks!!

Comment: What's the relationship between `publisher_id` and `publisher` in the `publishers` table? Why do you join to the `performance` table on `publisher`? Is it possible you have multiple `publisher_id` values with the same `publisher` value. It smells like it to me.

Comment: I actually have little say in the structure of the tables, unfortunately. In the publishers table, each publisher (a person) has a name and an ID number (publisher and publisher_id). I'm still green, so when you ask why I join to performance on publisher, I guess it's because I read a similar example and thought that was the way to go. I figured out the problem though, and it's that a publisher is listed once per merchant_id in the publishers table. The numbers being off by 8 times was due to the publisher's name being listed in the publishers table 8 times - one per merchant_id.

Comment: Ahh.  I figured something like that was the root cause of your combinatorial explosion.  Did you work out what to do?

Comment: I have not, no. I thought first to simply add another AND after the WHERE clause - WHERE performance.merchant_id='$merchant->ID' AND publishers.merchant_id='$merchant->ID' - but that does not work (and I think I understand why). I also investigated DISTINCT, but that led nowhere. I'm still on the hunt!